# How to pass data from a child component to a parent component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-component

I want to pass a dynamic pdf file from **BooksList** component to **Link** component in ***react-router-dom*** so that when I click the **BooksList** component inside a **Link** a pdf file will be passed to **Link**, then **Link** will forward this pdf file to **PDFViewer** component where this pdf file will be rendered. If it is impossible can you please suggest ways I can use to achieve this functionality. The example of the code before any data is passed is as follows:

```
<Link to="/pdf_viewer">
    <BooksList></BooksList>
</Link>

<Route path="/pdf_viewer">
    <PDFViewer></PDFViewer>
</Route>
```

BooksList

```
export class BooksList extends Component {
    render() {
        return this.props.books.map((book)=> (
          //Here there is book info rendered from props
          //PDF file is an attribute in book eg. book.pdf_file
          <div>Title: {book.book_title}</div>
        ));
    }
}

export default BooksList
```

**PDFViewer**

```js
export class PDFViewer extends Component {
    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        const { state: { pdfFile } } = this.props.location;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div key={book._id} className="pdfViewer">
                <embed src={ `data:application/pdf;base64, ${this.state}` } width="100%" height="600px"></embed>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default PDFViewer
```

**UnLinkedBooksList**

```js
export class UnLinkedBooksList extends Component {
    viewPDFHandler = pdfFile => {
        const {history} = this.props;
        history.push({
            pathname: "/pdfviewer",
            state: {
                pdfFile
            }
        });
    }
    render() {
        return this.props.books.map((book)=> (
            <div>
                <button type="button" onClick={()=> this.viewPDFHandler(book.pdf_file_byte["$binary"])}>View PDF</button>
            </div>
        ));
    }
}

const BooksList = withRouter(UnLinkedBooksList);

export default UnLinkedBooksList
```

**App**

```js
export class App extends Component {

  state = {
    books: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_all_books").then(res=>this.setState({books:res.data.all_books}))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        {/* Index Page */}
        <Route exact path="/">
          <div className="App">
            <SearchBar></SearchBar>
            <div className="row p-10">
              <div className="col-lg-6">
                <Link to="/pdf_viewer" className="text-decoration-none">
                  <BooksList books={this.state.books}></BooksList>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>        
          </div>
        </Route>

        {/* PDF Viewer Page */}
        <Route path="/pdf_viewer" className="text-decoration-none">
          <PDFViewer></PDFViewer>
        </Route>

       </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: The most common way to pass data from a child component to parent component is by passing a callback function from the parent to the child. Then the child can call the callback function and in that way give data to the parent. 

https://medium.com/@jasminegump/passing-data-between-a-parent-and-child-in-react-deea2ec8e654

Comment: Are you simply trying to pass a reference to a specific PDF file you want the `PDFViewer` component to fetch/load/render? Can you share a bit more code of how `BookList` has this PDF reference and tries to pass it? @Nermin, things are a little different with Routing/navigation where a link and route may be in completely separate React sub-trees, the `Link` sort of acts *as* the callback.

Comment: @Nermin thanks with the link, but how can I customize **Link** component to add a callback function

Comment: @DrewReese I added BooksList implementation summary. I need a way to pass book.pdf_file from BooksList to Link then to PDFViewer

Comment: I think you should reconsider the relationship between the one link and the array of book data mapped. How would the link know which book data to send with the route transition to the PDF viewer? Is the idea to have a "link" with each book, to click on a PDF specific to *that* book and open it in the PDF viewer? It may make more sense to have `BookList` access the router context's `history` and us imperative navigation with some route state.

Comment: Yes @DrewReese, that is the idea. Do you have anything that can help me to have a **BookList** access the router context's history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose the `history` object from the routing context in `BooksList` and add a handler for each mapped book to pass the PDF file reference as a route transition payload. Since `BooksList` is a class-based component and isn't rendered by a `Roiute` (*it probably should be, btw*), use the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component to decorate and inject [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props), (`history`, `location`, `match`).

```
class UnlinkedBooksList extends Component {
  viewPdfHandler = pdfFile => {
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.push({
      pathname: "/pdf_viewer",
      state: {
        pdfFile
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return this.props.books.map((book)=> (
      //Here there is book info rendered from props
      //PDF file is an attribute in book eg. book.pdf_file
      ...
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => viewPdfHandler(book.pdf_file)}
      >
        View PDF
      </button>
    ));
  }
}

const BooksList = withRouter(UnlinkedBooksList);

export default BooksList;
```

In App, default import `BooksList`, this is the linked component that will have the `location` prop.

```
import BooksList from './path/to/BooksList';
```

On the receiving end you can extract the route state. Render `PDFView` on the `component` prop so it also receives the route props, specifically, `location` so it can access the route state.

```
<Route path="/pdf_viewer" component={PDFViewer} />
```

In PDFViewer, access `pdfFile` from the `location` object:

```
const { state: { pdfFile } } = this.props.location;
```

Comment: I just replaced **BooksList** component with this **UnlinkedBooksList** component  in **App** component and got this error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

Comment: @ValentineSean So long as `UnlinkedBooksList` is decorated by `withRouter` and exported as `BooksList`, and `BooksList` is rendered somewhere *inside* a `Router`, then `history` should be defined. Mind sharing more complete code example showing how these two components are rendered in `App`?

Comment: I just edited the question. I added **PDFViewer, UnLinkedBooksList, App** components and one new line in **BooksList** component. After these implementations the error I got is: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined** highlighting the line **const { state: { pdfFile } } = this.props.location;** in **PDFViewer**

Comment: @ValentineSean Should default export the decorated/linked `BooksList` component, not the `UnLinkedBooksList` component, i.e. `export default BooksList;`. this is so the `location` object is injected as a prop. I wasn't sure how you were exporting the previous `BooksList` and didn't want to make any assumptions. I'll update my answer to add this detail in.

Comment: thanks, your answer led me to a desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following as;

```
...
const [url, setURL] = useState("");
const setPDFurl = (link)=>{
   setURL(link);
}
<Link to={`/pdf_viewer/${url}`}>
  <BooksList getURL = {setPDFurl }></BooksList>
</Link>
...
```

on your Booklist component,

```
 export default function booklist(props){
   ...
    const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
   ...
    props.getURL(url)
   ...
}
```

Hope it makes sense.